# Woocommerce not list orders all orders, why?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My `woocommerce` are not listing orders with status 'wc-expired'. I tried adding the 'wc_order_statuses' filter, but it still does not work.

```
add_filter('wc_order_statuses', function ($order_statuses){
    $order_statuses['wc-expired'] = _x( 'Expired', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    return $order_statuses;
});
```

[Row in Table wp_posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI0Yx.png)
[The Orders List in Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5J65.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new order status. Sample:

```
    function register_expired_order_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-expired', array(
        'label'                     => 'Expired',
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Expired <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Expired <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_expired_order_status' );

function add_expired_to_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $new_order_statuses = array();
    // add new order status after processing
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;
        if ( 'wc-processing' === $key ) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-expired'] = 'Expired';
        }
    }
    return $new_order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_expired_to_order_statuses' );
```